# How to upgrade a code from java 1.3 to 1.5

Tags: java, upgrade

I am a trainer and my project is to upgrade a transcompiler from Java 1.3 to 1.5, I am a beginner in Java and I want to khnow if there is a tool that will help me, I took the first step by reading the new features of 1.4 and 1.5 then we decided that I have to add this features : Generics - Metadata - Autoboxing - Enumerations - Var args - Enhanced for each loop.
So if you can tell me what is the next step and if there is a tool that upgrade the code to a recent version ? thank you

Comment: Please read [ask]. There's no tool that will upgrade code that I know of.

Comment: Java is usually pretty good at being backwards compatible. It will probably "just work"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just try to compile and then test the code, fix anything that doesn't work.

You don't *have* to use the new features just because they are there.

Why upgrade to 5 though? You should go to 7 really if going through the pain of doing an upgrade as the extra pain will be very small and you will be up to date for longer.

Comment: I did ask why not to upgrade to 1.7 and they said they will see if there is a feature that will need in 1.6 or 1.7, you suggest to compile the code but that's not what I need because the transcompiler work well but they want to change the source code ( I don't know why) to a recent version

Comment: 1.7 is more recent, is properly maintained, has security fixes, better performance, etc. It's not a matter of needing a specific feature.